# Numpy custom named datatype slice

Tags: numpy-slicing

I am creating a 3D sphere with 2D grid by selected latitudes and longitudes, which show the cartesian coordinates. This grid represent the key points to draw 3D sphere. Than I am creating X,Y,Z 3D coordinates  values from these cartesian coordinates with well known formula. Drawn sphere is shown in the attached picture. I am using a numpy named datatype as

```
np3d = np.dtype([('X', np.float), ('Y', np.float), ('Z', np.float)])
```

for 3D coordinates and

```
np2d = np.dtype([('L', np.float), ('B', np.float)])
```

for latitude/longitude grid. My python code is

```
import numpy as np, math
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, ticker, patches, font_manager as fmng
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, MultiCursor
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

fig3d = plt.figure('3D Sphere', figsize=(9.5,9.5))
fig3d.subplots_adjust(left=0.04, bottom=0.07, top=0.97, right=0.97, wspace=0, hspace=0)
prmgraf = dict(axis="both", direction='in',top=True, right=True)

ax3 = fig3d.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3.grid(False)
ax3.minorticks_on()
ax3.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax3.zaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(5))
ax3.tick_params(which='major', length=4, **prmgraf)
ax3.tick_params(which='minor', length=3, **prmgraf)
ax3.set_xlabel('Axis X')
ax3.set_ylabel('Axis Y')
ax3.set_zlabel('Axis Z')

ax3.set_xlim(-15.0, 15.0)
ax3.set_ylim(-15.0, 15.0)
ax3.set_zlim(-15.0, 15.0)

#            azim  elev
ax3.view_init(0., 180.)

# ---------------------------- settings ------------------------------
nLat = np.vstack(np.radians(np.arange(-65., 70., 5.)))
nLon = np.radians(np.arange(-180., 185., 5.))

np3d = np.dtype([('X', np.float), ('Y', np.float), ('Z', np.float)])
np2d = np.dtype([('L', np.float), ('B', np.float)])

LatN, LonN = (len(nLat), len(nLon))
SphrRadius = 14.5

#2D cartesian coordinates
pSphr = np.zeros(shape=(LatN, LonN), dtype=np2d)
pSphr['L'] = nLat
pSphr['B'] = nLon

#3D sphere coordinates
Spher = np.zeros(shape=(LatN, LonN), dtype=np3d)
Spher['X'] = SphrRadius*np.cos(pSphr['L'])*np.sin(pSphr['B'])
Spher['Y'] = SphrRadius*np.sin(pSphr['L'])
Spher['Z'] = SphrRadius*np.cos(pSphr['L'])*np.cos(pSphr['B'])

# draw sphere latitudes
for i in range(LatN):
    kx = Spher[i,:]['X']
    ky = Spher[i,:]['Y']
    kz = Spher[i,:]['Z']
    ax3.plot3D(kx, ky, kz, c='k',lw=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Z values of the sphere are changing between -15.0 and 15.0. I want to select **ONLY POSITIVE Z VALUES** in the "Spher variable". In other words, I want to draw half of the sphere in the Z direction. How can i do that in named datatype? Thanks for now to the friends who will answer.
[image: 3D Shpere]

Answer (score 1):

I found solution as

```
Spher[(Spher['Z'] < 0.)] = np.nan
```

But this is not the solution I expected. I want to select all points into a new variable as

```
ZPositive = Spher[(Spher['Z'] < 0.)]
```

But in this way, 2D data structure change into 1D data.
[image]